# How to remove/replace shower head holder?

Tags: shower

The shower head holder in my bathroom does not stay in place and I want to either fix it replace it.

I am struggling to remove it. I have managed to remove the screw (see images)
[image]

and the cap at the back

[image]

but can't figure out how to remove it from the slider bar.

[image]

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried separating the vertical bar at the plastic joint seen in the bottom pic, and sliding the thing down?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have to remove the rod then slide of the holder.

Otherwise tightening the screw should make it harder to turn